# Is my implementation of live search misusing PyQt5 methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have been working on a project that manages large datasets, utilizing PyQt5's QAbstractTableModel, QTableView, and QSortFilterProxyModel classes to display, filter, and modify the data. I will need expand this project in the future so I am trying my best to avoid bad practices. I am currently hesitant to move forward, as I just implemented a live search bar (table filters as you type) that seems to work fine on test data, but I am worried that running functions every time a key is entered may cause issues with larger datasets / more complex search conditions.

I  replicated my live search functionality below with a simple example that filters the "name" column in the table model as you type by connecting the QLineEdit.textChanged signal to update the proxy model's filter string every time a character is entered into the search bar.

I apologize if there is no *real issue* here, but I could not find any PyQt examples of this functionality. I just want to know if it is safe to use the textChanged signal to update the filter conditions on each key pressed, or if there is a better / more efficient way to accomplish this.

I have tried this functionality on larger data sets and with slightly more complex filter conditions, and it seems to run smoothly, but I am not proficient enough in PyQt to guess what type of issues may arise later on.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas
import sys

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.headings = ["name", "address", "number"]
        self.dataset = data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return self.dataset.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self.dataset.shape[0]

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.dataset.iloc[index.row()][index.column()]

        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.headings[section]

        return QtCore.QVariant()

class ProxyTableModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.filter_str = ''

    def setFilterStr(self, val):
        self.filter_str = val.lower()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        index = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
        data = self.sourceModel().data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

        return self.filter_str in data.lower()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(data)
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self, data):
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(500, 500)
        # create central display widget
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("central_widget")
        # create table view
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralWidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 500, 450))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("email_attributes")
        # create models & set proxy model to view
        self.mainModel = TableModel(data)
        self.proxyModel = ProxyTableModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.mainModel)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        # create column filter search bar
        self.searchBar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.searchBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 50))
        self.searchBar.textChanged[str].connect(self.filternames)
        # set central widget & connect slots
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def filternames(self, text):
        # set proxy model filter string
        self.proxyModel.setFilterStr(text)
        # set filterFixedString() to '' to refresh view
        self.proxyModel.setFilterFixedString('')

# underlying dataset for table model
df = {
    "name": ["John Smith", "Larry David", "George Washington"],
    "address": ["10 Forest Dr", "15 East St", "12 Miami Ln"],
    "phone_number": ["000-111-2222", "222-000-1111", "111-222-0000"]
}
data = pandas.DataFrame(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow(data)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

you should extend QLineEdit class and keyPressedEvent function to handle various keypressed events as it is below

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QRegExp)
class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initialize_component()

    def initialize_component(self):
        self.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_Tab:
            self.parent().focusNextChild()
        elif key == Qt.Key_Backtab:
            self.parent().focusPrevChild()
        else:
            return QLineEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: This makes sense, that way I can map the filtering behavior to the type of key pressed. Do you happen to know if running functions on every key press as I did above is too resource intensive, or am I underestimating PyQt?

Comment: you will need to customize keyPressEvent for your usecase + you may add
QApplication().setAttribute(Qt.AA_CompressHighFrequencyEvents)